# PayPal Rest setting notfyURL when creating a billing plan

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

Is it possible to specify the notify-url for a billing plan when creating it? I am using the PHP Rest SDK 1.7.4.

I did read somewhere that it is possible to do this in the merchant preferences, I have tried this but get the response:

`"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"merchant_preferences.notify_url","issue":"Field is invalid in a request."}]`

Is the recommendation to do this out of date like most of the information about using PayPal?

How can I get a cancellation of a billing agreement to notify a PayPal IPN handler (without setting the IPN address in the PayPal UI)? I don't want to use webhooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/issues/236

I think it don't supported yet~